# If $\frac ab=\frac bc=\frac cd$, then $\frac ad=\sqrt{{a^5+b^2c^2+a^3c^2\over b^4c+d^4+b^2cd^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If 
>   $$\frac ab=\frac bc=\frac cd$$
>
> then prove that 
>   $$\frac ad=\sqrt{{a^5+b^2c^2+a^3c^2\over b^4c+d^4+b^2cd^2}}$$

I don't want a full solution, just a little hint on how to start solving are welcome

Comment: Any hint would prove to be beneficial for me

Comment: That's not helping

Comment: The claim is wrong: take $a=-1$, $b=2$, $c=-4$, $d=8$.

Comment: That problem migh be  valid for only positive integers

Answer (score 1):

$$bc=ad, b^2=ac$$
$$b^2c^2=a^2d^2$$

$$b^4c^2=a^3d^2$$

Putting these values in the expression and taking out $$\frac ad$$ common the expression in surd cancels out.
Hence proved.

Answer (score 0):

Note

$$\frac{d^2}{a^2}\cdot {a^5+b^2c^2+a^3c^2\over b^4c+d^4+b^2cd^2}
=\frac{a^3+\frac{b^2c^2}{a^2}+ac^2}{\frac{b^4c}{d^2}+d^2+b^2c}
=\frac{a^3+d^2+ac^2}{a^3+d^2+ac^2}=1$$

Thus,

$$\sqrt{{a^5+b^2c^2+a^3c^2\over b^4c+d^4+b^2cd^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{d^2}}=\frac ad$$